# copy with ssh with port other than 22

Tags: remote-access, ssh, scp

How do I copy files from my local to some remote server which hosts ssh on port other than default (22).

I usually connect to the server using

> ssh username@remotehost.com -p 2000

Now I need to copy files with scp

> user@localbox:~$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remotebox.remotedomain.tld:~/.ssh/id_rsa_localbox.pub -p 2000

But this does not work.

Comment: `sshfs` is also an option :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`scp --help` or `man scp` would have told you the option was `-P port`. You also need to declare this before the file arguments:

```
scp -P 2000 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remotebox.remotedomain.tld:~/.ssh/id_rsa_localbox.pub
```

I also wouldn't trust `~`-relative links. Use full paths if you can.

But if you're copying IDs, `ssh-copy-id` also has an option to provide SSH connection options:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub '-p 2000 user@remotebox.remotedomain.tld'
```

Comment: // , Is there a way to search through the man pages for stuff like this?

Answer (score 4):

use a capital P

(it's in the man page...)

Answer (score 4):

You can create file **~/.ssh/config** and put relevant information for the remote host in there:

```
Host remotehost.com
Port 2000
User username
```

See man page for **ssh_config**.

This allows you to then run ssh as:

`ssh remotehost.com`

and scp as:

```
scp important_file remotehost.com:
```